# How to generate sql query from dot file with python?

Tags: python, dot

From file.dot, I need to generate sql query to insert into database.table

This is an extract of file.dot

```
digraph {
    "source.table1" -> "db.dep1"[label="CHEC_DATE"];
    "source.table2" -> "db.dep2"[label="CHECK_MAX_DATE"];
    "db.dep2" -> "source.table3"[label="CHECK_DATE"];
    "source.table2" -> "db.table4"[label="CHECK_MAX_DATE"];
 }
```

I need to generate query as

```
INSERT INTO dep_table (entity_name_1, entity_name_2, flag_dep) VALUES ('source.table1', 'db.dep1', 'CHECK_DATE');



INSERT INTO dep_table (entity_name_1, entity_name_2, flag_dep) VALUES ('source.table2', 'db.dep2', 'CHECK_MAX_DATE');
```

And so on

I am using Graphviz to read data from file.dot

```
import sys
from os import path, access, R_OK
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing import nx_agraph
import os
from graphviz import Source
file = open('file.dot', 'r')
text=file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

So each line from the .dot file makes a sql query?
and the values you need to insert are all between double quotations?
if so you can use regular expressions to find all strings between double quotations and then make the sql command
like so:

```
import re
for line in text :
    values = re.findall('".+"',line)
    sql_command = 'INSERT INTO X VAlUES' + '(' +values[0] + ',' values[1]  #and so on
```

Comment: the result of values = re.findall('".+"',line)
is all the line. 
How to split only string between " "?